# Manually Logout from previous browser session if user login in any new browser in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, session, cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

I am working on the Cakephp 3.

I need user only login **once** at time.

I am using Cakephp **Auth** component for the login into app. I worked with **database session** and **cake session**.

But when i am try to delete Session Manually from database or delete the session file form **app/tmp/session**, the session re-create again.

I don't want to disallow second login of user, but want to destroy previous session.

how can I achieve single session of user in Cakephp 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the current session id of the user in the users table:

- Before login, check if the current session id is present in the users table for that user.
- If the session id is present, destroy the old session by deleting it from the sessions table.
- After login, store the generated session id.

Comment: Lorenzo I tried this method but session automatically created in /app/tmp/sessions on remote machine ,I have to manually delete the session file

Comment: Don't use cake sessions, it is easier for this use case to use database sessions

Comment: @JoséLorenzo I know it's been a while since this was posted and an answer given. But I'm working on this exact issue right now. I was wondering if you could elaborate on how to do this exactly? I've got database sessions setup and they are working, but I can't figure out how to check if a specific session exists, and how to delete a specific session.